# Burninate [unset]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unset) tags seem like pretty useless tags.  Should they be killed hard?

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

These tags don't really describe any content, in the context.  They only make sense in the context of other tags.  e.g.

- [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unset) & [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unset) & [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb)

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

It is on-topic.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post

Maybe I just can't see it, but I can't think of any way that [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unset).  The fact that there are zero followers of the tag highlights that it's not really a useful term.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts

[unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unset) is being used for different things in different questions.

Is it worth it?  I don't have anything to compare it to to decide.  It's not actively evil.

Comment: Thank you for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: The very short format of this request and its content both indicate that you may not have read Shog9's answer. Why do you think they're useless? Are they harmful in any way? Plus, the wording of your question seems to suggest simply removing the tag from questions, which would be a very counter-productive thing to do.

Comment: I hadn't read it, just saw it on a questions.  I will read it before participating in future.

Comment: How is "unset" a ontopic question?

Comment: It's tenuous, but I can't think it's anything but about programming.

Comment: Looking at the [first question to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275766/can-you-unset-many-variables-at-once-in-php), it was specifically about the `unset()` method in PHP.

Comment: So, are you saying that every php method should have a tag?

Comment: No, but isn't that covered in other points?  It's far too fine grained.  It is, inarguably, about programming though.

Answer (score 10):

The vast majority of these are about a PHP function named "unset". A good portion of the rest regard a bash command of the same name.

There's some minor ambiguity here, but honestly I don't see where it's causing any harm; a few minutes spent cleaning up questions where it's used as a synonym for "null" would suffice.